# hmd.mx from demography package generate errors

Tags: r

I'm using the hmd.mx command from the package demography. My first command is to read in mx data with following command

```
norway <- hmd.mx("NOR", username, password, "Norway")
```

already this gives me a warning `NAs introduced by coercion`. Tracing the error with `traceback()` I get `No traceback available`. This doesn't make any sense to me; what causes this and how can I correct this?

I don't want my results be in danger of falsification because the read in functions is not working, I rather it be caused by me using the wrong commands :)

Comment: There is no traceback because you got a warning, not an error.

Comment: Ok. But what does the warning mean? I find many solutions online but not explaining the cause of it.